# Save and recall user highlighted selection in text area

Tags: jquery, text, tags, save, highlight

I am using HTML, php, mySQL, and jquery as tools. I currently have an area of my website where users leave notes on their interactions with clients. They can add tags to the notes so they can record what topics (tags) the note covers. My goal is to go a step further. I want to be able to record what topics specific text within the note covers. I want the client to be able to select text within the text area to be saved as referrIng to a specific tag. I want to be able to recall all text within their submission they tagged as related to the tag. This would be different from what I currently have of tagging the submission as a whole.

For example, I could search through their notes for the tag CONCERNS and instead of bringing up all notes that have been tagged with the tag CONCERNS, what we currently do, I would like to bring up the specific text within the note that was highlighted/selected as relating to CONCERNS or at least the note with that specific text highlighted.

I am thinking I will have to somehow save the information of at what character within the text the highlight begins and what character the highlight ends. This way that selection can be recalled and highlighted for the user when they are reviewing their notes and tags.

I have searched for tools/plugins to help me accomplish this task for months without luck. Can anyone offer any help/suggestions?

Comment: This might help you http://motyar.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/get-user-selected-text-with-jquery-and.html

Answer (score 0):

If the selected text is contained inside an `INPUT` or `TEXTAREA` element I use [jQuery-caret](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/caret) for retrieving the selected text.

Usage:

```
var input = $("#selector");
var range = input.caret();
var text = null;
// Get selected text
text = input.val().substr(range.start, range.end - 1);
```